# Script does not filter swear words discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

I`m trying to create my discord.py bot to delete messages with swear words and, after that make an announcement who made that and abuse him for his behaviour. I load a bad words list in .txt File looks like: 'Badword, badword2, etc'

i`ve tried many ways but i really do not get how to do that.

[image]

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
import datetime 
from itertools import cycle
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

with open('badwords.txt','r') as file:
    bad_words = [bad_word.strip(', ').lower() for bad_word in file.read()]

@bot.event 
async def on_message(message):
     if any(bad_word in message.content.strip().lower() for bad_word in bad_words):
           await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, твое сообщение не прошло цензуру")
           await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
           await bot.process_commands(message)
```

The bot calls himself too much, looks like it is recursive or smth!
he reacts not only on bad words but on good ones too.

Comment: What's does badwords.txt looks like ?

Comment: badword1, badword2, badword3, ..... and to the end. it looks exactly like i spelled now.

Comment: Straight in big line

Comment: i guess that problem within reading file because i have russian words so when i print whole list that gives me: x04c\x04n\x04,\x00 \x00e\x04c etc.

Comment: Something with encrypting maybe I should try codecs

Comment: If you're on python3 (if not you should), add an encoding parameter to open() that match your file (put everything in utf-8 if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solve that problem now. Like **polku** said that is an iteration error and that is !
Also I used russian words and they made mistakes in encryption i guess(you can solve it by **MIMEtext**). Here is my final code:

```
with open('badwords.txt') as file:
    file = file.read().split()


#----------------------------------EVENTS----------------------------------

@bot.event 
async def on_message(message):
    for badword in file:
        if badword in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}! Your message has not passed moderation!')
        else:
            await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best solution here is to use `re`.

Also you're using `GuildChannel.purge` when you could just be using `message.delete` if at the very least for clarity as well as not deleting the message it sends, and `bot.process_commands` will never be called unless there is a bad word if you use that logic so call it if there isn't a bad word or just put it at the end of the method.

```
with open('badwords.txt','r') as f:
    bad_words = '|'.join(s for l in f for s in l.split(', '))
    bad_word_checker = re.compile(bad_words).search

@bot.event 
async def on_message(message)
    if bad_word_checker(message.content):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(...)
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: and then this has happened
line 16, in on_message
    if bad_word_checker(message):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: `message.content` My mistake

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
[bad_word.strip(', ').lower() for bad_word in file.read()]
```

file.read() reads the whole file in one string, by iterating on it you're iterating characters of a string, and so with your list comprehension, bad_words doesn't contain words but letters.
In the example you show, the user sent messages of one character, so if the character appears at least once in the file, your bot considers that as a bad word.

The exact solution depends on your badwords.txt format, you say it's all the words on the same line separated by ', ', then this should work

```
bad_words = file.read().strip().lower().split(', ')
```